# How can I select an element that will exist in future with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, svg

I have an SVG that I will add elements to. And on `mousemove` this elements should move, so I want to select the elements that exist in the future:

```
// #svgcanvas exist always
// #templine will exist in the future
$('#svgcanvas').bind('mousemove', function(e) {         
    $('#templine').setAttributeNS(null, "x2", e.pageX);
    $('#templine').setAttributeNS(null, "y2", e.pageY);
});
```

Here are the `#templine` element created on a `click` event:

```
$('#svgcanvas').bind('click', function(e) {
    var line = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "line");
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "templine");
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", points[0].x);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", points[0].y);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", e.pageX);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", e.pageY);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "stroke:rgb(100,100,100)");
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(line);
});
```

This code is not working, because `#templine` doesn't exist at the time of binding. Is there any other way I can solve this with jQuery? I have tried to use `.live()` instead of `.bind()` but that didn't help in this case.

Comment: no, there is something else messed up if this is your problem. The `$('#templine')` will be executed again and again on every event (which by the way may have an impact on performance). Why do you believe that this is the problem and nothing else?

Comment: I'm guessing from your code that there will be multiple `templine` elements, so use the `class` attribute instead of the `id` attribute.

Comment: by the way: The last 7 lines of your svgcanvas/click function could be shortend to `$(line).attr('id', '#templine').attr('x1',points[0].x).attr('y1', points[0].y).attr('x2', e.pageX).attr('y2', e.pageY).attr('style', 'stroke:rgb(100,100,100)').appendTo('#canvase');` I believe. If jQuery does not behave strange on svg...

Comment: @yankee: I want the `$('#templine')` to be executed on every mousemove event, because the line should change when the mouse moves. So I think it's right. I will try to shorten my code after your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: @waitinforantrain: This code is simplyfied, I will only create a single element with id "templine", on the first click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I can see is that `$('#templine')` is a jQuery object, and therefore doesn't have the `setAttributeNS` method.

Try this instead:

```
$('#templine').attr("x2", e.pageX);
$('#templine').attr("y2", e.pageY);
```

Comment: Good catch, but it's not the problem mentioned by OP

Comment: @Juan: yes it is.  "because #templine doesn't exist at the time of binding" is not correct.  The event is bound to `$('#svgcanvas')`, which exists, so that's fine.  When the function runs, `$('#templine')` will return a jQuery object (it may be empty if the element does not exist, but it will still be a valid jQuery object).  jQuery objects don't have `setAttributeNS`.

Comment: Don't think so, #templine is not created until you click #svgcanvas. You don't have to explain again that OP is trying to call an HTMLElement method on a jQuery object.

Comment: @Juan: why does it matter if `#templine` exists or not?  If you try to call a function on an empty jQuery object, it just doesn't do anything.  If you call a function that does not exist, it throws an error and crashes.

Comment: @Rocket: Wow, I completely missed that. You may want to propose to use attr() instead of setAttributeNS...

Comment: @yankee: I'm not sure what `setAttributeNS` does, so I don't know what the correct replacement is, nor do I know how jQuery treats SVG elements.

Comment: @Rocket: setAttributeNS is like setAttribute (which is attr in jQuery), just that allows you to set a namespace. But if you set the Namespace to null, then that should be the same as using the function without the NS...

Comment: @Rocket: I see what you mean, didn't make sense to me because there isn't a setAttributeNs method in jQuery, so the caller would have to retrieve the first element of the jQuery object to call it anyway. However, if calling attr() is good enough, then just change would be good enough to fix the problem.

Comment: I think you are right, I just have to change to this and it works. But I have to make sure that this code only runs when "templine" exist.

Comment: @Jonas: If `#templine` does not exist, then `$('#templine').attr("x2", e.pageX);` will not do anything.  It won't throw an error or crash, it just won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#canvas').bind('click', function(e) {
    var line = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "line");
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "templine");
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", points[0].x);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", points[0].y);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", e.pageX);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", e.pageY);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "stroke:rgb(100,100,100)");
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(line);
    $('#svgcanvas').bind('mousemove', function(e) {         
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", e.pageX);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", e.pageY);
    });
});
```

Also, @Rocket's suggestion is also valid. Updating my answer...

Comment: You should include Rocket's suggestion: `$(...)[0].setAtttribute...`

Comment: Point well noted. I noticed it after posting my answer.

Comment: For performance, I would just use `line.setAttributeNS` instead of querying the DOM twice on every mouse move

Comment: Thx agn! Obviously my mind is not working optimally today! Updating again!

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Handler checks if '#templine' exists, if it doesn't, it does nothing.
- Do not install the handler until you create #templine (at the bottom of your second handler)

Also, don't call  `$('#templine')` twice in a row, save the result in a variable.